# Defined an array internally, returning undefined when called externally

Tags: javascript

I have an internal script that has a array defined like so. It also has an external script which reads the data set in the "data" array. I made a mock-up of how I have things set-up, if this is no help I will provide a link to the actual page.

Internal Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  data = {    
   "id": "1",
   "name": "joe"
  }
</script>
```

External Script:

```
(function(window, document, undefined) {
  find = {
    postCount: function(){
      var user = data.name;
    }
  };

  find.postCount(); // If called here, data is undefined.

})(this, document);
```

Problem:
If I call the function anywhere but from the console it returns undefined.

I'm still fairly new to javascript so I'm probably making a stupid mistake or something, if you need anymore details let me know. Also, apologies for the quality of the post, it's my first time posting here.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you have your scripts embedded in that order (data definition first, script with the automatically called function second), then I see no reason why this should not work (assuming scripts are embedded "normally", no async/defer or anything). Please provide a jsfiddle.net example where we can see your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be including the external javascript file before the script block declaring data. Doing this would mean that `find.postCount();` is being called before `data` is declared. Calling it from the console would then work because at that point `data` is declared.

Note also that calling `find.postCount();` shows as returning undefined in the console window when I call it (because the function declares the variable `user` but never actually returns anything.

Comment: Thanks, it was a matter of order. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks, you help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't that be `data = { ...`?

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake in the mock up. The post is fixed now.